# Identityserver4 return custom values userinfo endpoint

Tags: identityserver4, userinfo

Should IdentityServer4's UserInfo endpoint return all the claims that I have in my ASPNetUserClaims table for a given user or do I need some special configuration to get them?  Right now I am only seeing the default values being returned and before I waste a lot of time trying to get this to work with my custom values I want to make sure I am not doing something wrong.  Worse case I can use some of the other existing entries to store my data (challenge question and response) but I would prefer to store them using those names (rather than in fields like middle_name and nickname for instance)

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html), ***The caller needs to send a valid access token representing the user. Depending on the granted scopes, the UserInfo endpoint will return the mapped claims (at least the openid scope is required)***

The proper way to get your custom claims is to

1. [in IdentityServer configuration] Add the custom claim types to a scope(resource) and add that scope to allowed scopes list of the client.
2. [in Client]Request that scope(resource) from your client.

If you add your identity server configuration and client configuration to the question it will help you to get more specific answer.